# Estoy intentando instalar el paquete rriskDistributions en R y no lo logro

Tags: r, instalacion, packages

```
> install.packages("rriskDistributions")
Installing package into ‘/cloud/lib/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/4.3’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
also installing the dependency ‘tkrplot’

trying URL 'http://rspm/default/__linux__/focal/latest/src/contrib/tkrplot_0.0-27.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 33509 bytes (32 KB)
==================================================
downloaded 32 KB

trying URL 'http://rspm/default/__linux__/focal/latest/src/contrib/rriskDistributions_2.1.2.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 116173 bytes (113 KB)
==================================================
downloaded 113 KB

* installing *source* package ‘tkrplot’ ...
** package ‘tkrplot’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
** using staged installation
configure: creating ./config.status
config.status: creating src/Makevars
** libs
using C compiler: ‘gcc (Ubuntu 9.4.0-1ubuntu1~20.04.2) 9.4.0’
gcc -I"/opt/R/4.3.2/lib/R/include" -DNDEBUG -I/usr/include/tcl8.6 -I/usr/include/tcl8.6  -I/usr/local/include    -fpic  -g -O2  -c tcltkimg.c -o tcltkimg.o
tcltkimg.c:3:10: fatal error: tk.h: No such file or directory
    3 | #include <tk.h>
      |          ^~~~~~
compilation terminated.
make: *** [/opt/R/4.3.2/lib/R/etc/Makeconf:191: tcltkimg.o] Error 1
ERROR: compilation failed for package ‘tkrplot’
* removing ‘/cloud/lib/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/4.3/tkrplot’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘tkrplot’ had non-zero exit status
ERROR: dependency ‘tkrplot’ is not available for package ‘rriskDistributions’
* removing ‘/cloud/lib/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/4.3/rriskDistributions’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘rriskDistributions’ had non-zero exit status

The downloaded source packages are in
    ‘/tmp/RtmpDMuo3Y/downloaded_packages’
```

Comment: Ese error te está indicando que faltan paquetes de desarrollo en tu sistema operativo, prueba abrir una terminal y ejecutar `sudo apt-get install tcl-dev tk-dev`,  luego reintenta la instalación en R

Comment: que debo instalar para ejecutar esto?

Comment: Estas usando ubuntu?  Tienes que abrir una terminal, un `bash`, `gnome-terminal`  o como se llame en tu distribución

Comment: gracias por ayudar.  Es la primera vez que me enfrento a R.  Por lo que no sé que es ubutun, ni bash.  Leí en internet pero esta fuera de lo que conozco.

Comment: Bueno, si no sabes lo que es Ubuntu, entiendo que estás ejecutando un RStudio desde la nube. Puede ser? ubuntu es el sistema operativo dónde estaría ejecutandose tu script, lo digo por el error `using C compiler: ‘gcc (Ubuntu 9.4.0-1ubuntu1~20.04.2) 9.4.0’`

Comment: En efecto estoy usando r cloud.  Como puedo hacer para poder usar esa libreria desde cloud

Comment: Francamente no sé si Cloud te permite hacer instalaciones a nivel sistema opertivo (no lo recuerdo), si te habilita el acceso a una consola dónde puedas escribir comandos de linux, podrías intentar instalar los paquetes que en principio parecerían estar faltando: `sudo apt-get install tcl-dev tk-dev`